# Can you make all objects of a class do the same thing with one method call?

Tags: swift, animation, inheritance, uibutton, jquery-animate

Sorry, this might seem like a silly question. If I've got a class LargeButton that inherits from UIButton is there a way for me to say that when any LargeButton is clicked, ALL LargeButton objects animate and disappear?

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        AllLargeButtons.alpha = 0 
        }, completion: { finished in
            AllLargeButtons.hidden = true
```

Is there a way to do something like this without storing all the LargeButtons in an array first?

EDIT:

```
class LargeButton: UIButton {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(oneLargeButtonTapped), name: "oneOfLargeButtonsTapped", object: nil)
    }

    func oneLargeButtonTapped() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0 // Here you will get the animation you want
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.hidden = true // Here you hide it when animation done
        })
    }

    deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}


class viewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
             NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("oneOfLargeButtonsTapped", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Creating the LargeButton:

```
    lazy var aButton: LargeButton = {
        let button = LargeButton()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(oneLargeButtonTapped), name: "oneOfLargeButtonsTapped", object: nil)

//        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(oneLargeButtonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return button
    }()
```

Answer (score 4):

When creating a LargeButton object register it to receive notifications:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LargeButton.oneLargeButtonTapped), name: "oneOfLargeButtonsTapped", object: nil)
```

When one of the LargeButtons is tapped post the notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("oneOfLargeButtonsTapped", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

In the method "oneLargeButtonTapped" implement the desired behavior.

Don't forget to unregister the buttons from the Notification Center before they are destroyed.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I put the code that posts the notification? IN the oneLargeButtonTapped I imagine correct?

Comment: can you give me an example of oneLargeButtonTapped() method? 

Should it be oneLargeButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
     // perform animation here
}

Comment: @tryingtolearn - you post the notification in the method that receives the tap. So when one button is tapped it will notify all the other buttons (and itself). The button that receives the notification will perform the oneLargeButtonTapped method. In this method you should put the code of the animation. **Don't forget to unregister from the notifications, otherwise it may result in crashes and/or memory leaks.**

Comment: Right but how do I refer to each of the buttons? In the OP I write the code for the animation, but how do I specify a LargeButton there?

Comment: @tryingtolearn - you implement it in the LargeButton class 'UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0 
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.hidden = true'

Comment: can you check my edit and see if this is correct? I'm not sure I have done it properly.

Comment: @tryingtolearn - I have edited your edit. All the LargeButton objects should be connected to the 'buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)' method.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the way you're suggesting, no. That would require that each class keeps track of all existing objects, which they don't. You could implement this yourself by having initializers add new instances to a `static` `Array`, but you shouldn't. What happens if you ever wish to have objects of the same class, which don't animate with the rest?

Instead, you should create an array of all the objects you wish to animate. Have `LargeButton`'s `IBAction` call a method which iterates over the array of objects, and animats them.

Comment: Or raise a custom event and then handle it from each button instance.

Comment: What do you mean, @chrisp_68?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov If I'm writing it programmatically I've got no real choice but to write the action for each of the existing LargeButtons I guess right?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov should I not one to do it via an array I mean.

Comment: Sorry I dont know anything about swift specifically but events are pretty standard across technologies. Take a look here: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/05/swift-events.html and also client side there is a good example of how to trigger and subscribe to events using jquery here. https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events. Alternativly can you use a jquery selector

Comment: You can have one action in common for all `LargeButton`s